# C++ Qt QCustomPlot .txt data plotting, index out of range error

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

Hi I am trying to plot data from a .txt file to the graph in QCustomPLot
I am appending the data from QTextStream to the double vector, when I do this I get an error

```
"ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file /Users/.../Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qvector.h, line 436"
```

I changed the size of the vector to auto size, throws no errors, but does not plot the data, graph remains empty. So I'm sure the error has to do with my string lenghts. The other posts on the ASSERT failure just did not make much sense.

the data is like so:

```
1,2
2,3
0,1
```

and my code is this:

```
QVector<double> v;
QFile textFile("/Users/10Exahertz/Documents/Hall Data/Test/data.txt");
if(textFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    //auto size = v.size();
    QVector<double> x(2), y(2);
    double d;
    QTextStream textStream(&textFile);
    while (!textStream.atEnd()) {
        textStream >> d;
        if(textStream.status() == QTextStream::Ok){
            v.append(d);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = i;
        y[i] = v[i];
    }
ui->customPlot->addGraph();
// create graph and assign data to it:
//ui->customPlot->addGraph();
ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
```

Comment: the problem is simple, c ++ will not guess that there is a comma, you can only read the first element, that is, the 1, then there is a comma that can not be converted to double, so status will not be Ok coming out of the loop with a `v `of size 1 you in the for loop assume that it is size 2 causing the error. I do not understand what you want to plot, from the .txt that you want to show only the first column? The first vs the second column? Only the first row?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to plot the data like a classic scatter plot, so the first column is the X data, the second the Y data